# How to stop getting duplicate data in django_restframework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get all data by filter user and mode i am able to filter all data but i also getting duplicate data so how to stop getting duplicate data in django rest-framework.

Here is **json file**.

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "too": "2019-09-28",
            "fromm": "2019-09-28",
            "user": 1,
            "total_milage": 20,
            "total_movingtime": 20.0,
            "total_averagespeed": 10.0,
            "total_kg": 20,
            "total_co2_save": 20,
            "total_boxes": 20,
            "total_user": 20,
            "total_letter": 20,
            "total_ship_weight": 20,
            "total_pack": 20
        },
        {
            "too": "2019-09-28",
            "fromm": "2019-09-28",
            "user": 2,
            "total_milage": 12,
            "total_movingtime": 10.0,
            "total_averagespeed": 10.0,
            "total_kg": 12,
            "total_co2_save": 10,
            "total_boxes": 10,
            "total_user": 10,
            "total_letter": 12,
            "total_ship_weight": 10,
            "total_pack": 10
        },
        {
            "too": "2019-09-28",
            "fromm": "2019-09-28",
            "user": 1,
            "total_milage": 20,
            "total_movingtime": 20.0,
            "total_averagespeed": 10.0,
            "total_kg": 20,
            "total_co2_save": 20,
            "total_boxes": 20,
            "total_user": 20,
            "total_letter": 20,
            "total_ship_weight": 20,
            "total_pack": 20
        },
```

Here is **`views.py`**

```
class ReportView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.all().distinct()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReportSerializer
    # pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ReportFilter
```

and here is **`serilizers.py`**

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_milage = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_movingtime = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_averagespeed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_kg = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_co2_save = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_boxes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_letter = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_ship_weight = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_pack = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['too', 'fromm','user', 'total_milage', 'total_movingtime', 'total_averagespeed', 'total_kg', 'total_co2_save',
                  'total_boxes', 'total_user', 'total_letter', 'total_ship_weight', 'total_pack', 'too', 'fromm']


    # def get_mode(self, obj):
    #     totalpiece = Delivery.objects.filter(mode__exact="bike")

    # def get_user(self, obj):
    #     return obj.user.username

    def get_total_letter(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Delivery.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user,mode=obj.mode).aggregate(
            total_letter=Sum('letteritems'))
        return totalpieces["total_letter"]

    def get_total_ship_weight(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Delivery.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user.id,mode=obj.mode).aggregate(
            total_ship_weight=Sum('shipweight'))
        return totalpieces["total_ship_weight"]

// and so on.........
```

And i a trying to filter data by specific user and specific mode but i geting repeating data so how to stop getting repeating data

Answer (score 1):

try to use `Delivery.objects.all().distinct('id')`

Comment: Saved the day.  Why though???

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple rows in database for same user. to get unique with user or any other field you have to pass that argument in `distinct`.

For above example In `ReportView` queryset add field names for distinct`

`queryset = Delivery.objects.all().distinct('user')`

More about [distict queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: i am getting this error "  

DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" when i put `queryset = Delivery.objects.all().distinct('user')` this

Comment: what is your database backend?